# Hibernate detached entity error while removing an entity

Tags: java, hibernate

According to [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-hibernate-entity-state-transitions/) as long as I use `org.hibernate.Session` instead of `JPA`, it should be allowed to remove also detached entities using the `session.remove(entity)`

However whenever I try to remove an entity, it doesn't allow me to remove it due to detached state.

The line is like this;

```
employeeDao.delete(employee)
```

Even if I try to remove like this

```
employeeDao.delete(employeeDao.findById(employee.getId)):
```

it gives the same error and doesn't remove it.

The exception is that

> Unexpected RuntimeException
>      Last cause: Removing a detached instance rd.core.model.Employee#69

The stack trace is

> Root cause:
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance
>   rd.core.model.Employee#69
>        at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaDeleteEventListener.performDetachedEntityDeletionCheck(JpaDeleteEventListener.java:69)
>        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:106)
>        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:73)
>        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireDelete(SessionImpl.java:920)
>        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:896)
>        at rd.core.persistence.AbstractHibernateDao.delete(AbstractHibernateDao.java:35)
>        at rd.core.services.EmployeeManagerImpl.deleteEmployee(EmployeeManagerImpl.java:186)
>        at com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaLocalTxnInterceptor.invoke(JpaLocalTxnInterceptor.java:66)
>        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

I think I am messing up with something completely wrong. Even this causes to the same exception.

```
 public void remove(Employee employee) {
        getCurrentSession().merge(employee);
        getCurrentSession().delete(employee);
    }
```

Here is my POJO

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TMP_EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee implements Identifiable<Integer> {

private static final String ID_GENERATOR_NAME = "TMP_EMPLOYEE_ID_SEQ";
public static final String PROP_FULL_NAME = "fullName";
public static final String PROP_ID = "id";
public static final String PROP_DEP = "department";

public static final String COLUMN_FULL_NAME = "FULL_NAME";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "emp.ID";
public static final String COLUMN_DEP = "NAME";

@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = ID_GENERATOR_NAME)
@SequenceGenerator(name = ID_GENERATOR_NAME, sequenceName = "S_EMPLOYEE_ID", allocationSize = 1)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "FULL_NAME", nullable = false, length = 60)
@Basic
private String fullName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "DEP_ID", referencedColumnName ="ID", nullable = false)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private Department department;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}

public Integer getDepartmentId() {
    return 0;
}

public void setDepartmentId(Integer departmentId) {

}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o)
        return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Employee))
        return false;

    Employee that = (Employee) o;

    if (getId() != null ? !getId().equals(that.getId()) : that.getId() != null)
        return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return getId() != null ? getId().hashCode() : 0;
}

@Override
public Integer getIdentity() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return "Id: " + this.id + " Employee Name: " + this.fullName;
}

public Department getDepartment() {
    return department;
}

public void setDepartment(Department department) {
    this.department = department;
}
```

This may sound simple but What causes exactly to change the entities states like this and why can't I remove it even if it is detached?

Note: I am delegating the same employee instance through the classes. So it is always the same entity.

if you need further data, please ask for it. I actually don't know which data can help to figure out this.

Comment: what is a error?

Comment: If hibernate tell you that your entity is detached, just try to reattaches it before delete it.

Comment: show your pojo please

Comment: I have added the Exception, StackTrace and the POJO

Comment: are you sure you wrap your find / delete sequence inside a transaction? that `find` maybe outside of transaction so `find` will return state of detached objects held in memory

Comment: @Angga I have a method that retrieves all the employees at first. This isn't inside the transaction.I mean I didn't put the transactional annotation for find operations. I will try this. Edit; I put Transactional annotation for all the get methods in the service. It is still the same.

Comment: if you can not get the persistence entity using `find`, use `Session.update()` or `Session.merge()` for reattachment of detached instances, but this will update your entity(which maybe you didnt care because you want to delete it anyway).

Comment: I thought about it. it seems this is the way to make it work. However it is bad to reach the session from the service class. So I should create a remove method in the DAO layer and in the remove I should merge the entity again. This is the working way, but is it the right way? I still don't know why hibernate is detaching this entity right after finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read this about "[why can't I remove it even if it is detached](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch03.html)", there you can find this :

> It is important to note that Hibernate itself can handle deleting
>   detached state. JPA, however, disallows it. The implication here is
>   that the entity instance passed to the org.hibernate.Session delete
>   method can be either in managed or detached state, while the entity
>   instance passed to remove on javax.persistence.EntityManager must be
>   in managed state.

And about why the object detached right after you `find` it, we didn't know about it either without seeing the code. But you can read it in the same article above about how the entity can became detached and how to reattach it in section **3.8. Working with detached data**.

In summary about what you should **not do** to prevent detachement of object is:

1. Close persistence context
2. Clearing the persistence context
3. Evicting a particular entity from the persistence context
4. Object serialization(deserialized object will be detached, serialized object not always)

But if you can't prevent that, you should reattach the object using something like Session.saveOrUpdate(), Session.update() or Session.merge(). Or.. simply using hibernate's(not JPA) Session.delete().

Comment: You were right. In the find method, I was using a query instead of using session.get. So it was closing the persistence context and opening another one. I guess that was the thing?

Answer (score 0):

This is the Entity Life Cycle for Hibernate. So session.update should do the trick to reattach the detached entity. However, update can cause some bugs, so I see that people generally use merge to reattach the entity.

[image]

So it might be related if you initialize your entity lazily.

> When Hibernate reads data from the database, the data is hold in the
> session. You can save references to the data - for example in your
> HTTP request. Once the transaction is committed and the session is
> closed you can not load any further data with this session. Hibernate
> loads only the first object and replaces collections of other objects
> by a proxy. If you access the proxy, Hibernate uses the current
> session to initialize the proxy and load the entries from the
> database.

As far as I understood, you are using Open-Session-in-View pattern. So try to read these materials.

[Lazy Initialization](http://www.laliluna.de/jpa-hibernate-guide/ch02s02.html)

[Open Session In View](http://www.laliluna.de/jpa-hibernate-guide/ch13s07.html#opensessioninview)

Problem can be caused due to multiple reasons, so it is really important what you do for what.